# System.out.println it doesn't show in the terminal

Tags: java

I typed the code but it didn't show in the terminal can anyone help :) ?

[image]

Comment: Did you run the program?

Comment: You need to `right click` and select the option as `Run Java`. That will run the program and will print the output on the terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the program to see the output, if you have run the program from VS code.

[image: find the output in debug console or output]

If not then open a terminal/command line go the directory where your Hello.java file is located.

In the terminal, run the command:

```
javac Hello.java
```

The file Hello.class should be created in your current directory try running.

```
java Hello
```

Hope you have java environment variables. if not set the environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

First Type this code in any Text editor(VSCode) and then save it by the name you are defining inside code(Which is Hello.java) and then open CMD or Terminal(of VSCode) at
where the file (Hello.java) is saved by you
____________********************Then********************

First Command

1. javac Hello.java

Second Command

2. java Hello

Answer (score 0):

You need to `right click` and select the option `Run Java`. That will run the program and will print the output on the terminal.

```html
<html><head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"></head><body><video controls="" autoplay="" name="media"><source src="https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial/run-debug.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video></body></html>
```